# mpirun breaks out the while-loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell, mpi

I'm trying to run a batch script with *mpirun* nested in a while-loop, like this

```
while read line
do
    mpirun -np 4 myexec > /dev/null
done < case.txt
```

But this script only returns one loop result. Whenever the executable is done the loop is broken.
I also tried to run the code without parallel and it works fine.
If I replace the *while read line* with a normal while-loop, say, *while [ $count -le 9 ]*, it also works.
For-loop is Okay as well.
I just cannot figure it out. Hope somebody could tell me why this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like `mpirun` reads from `stdin`, which is `case.txt` in this case. That would read all lines from the file during the first run of the loop. On the next attempt of `read` the file has been fully read already and that's why the loop ends.

Try to assign `/dev/null` to its stdin:

```
while read line
do
    mpirun -np 4 myexec > /dev/null < /dev/null
done < case.txt
```

Comment: Glad to see that it helps